# How to center input boxes (bootstrap form)

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-full">

      <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="background-color:#fff" ng-show="registrationForm">
        <p class="genericText">Fill out the following information to create your profile.</p>
    <!-- FORM -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
   <form name="goalsForm" ng-submit="submitForm(goalsForm.$valid)">
    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block;'>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Create Password</label>
    <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="inputGoal" placeholder="Enter a password" ng-model="goal">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="inputGoal" placeholder="Confirm your password" ng-model="goal">
  </div>
</div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Complete</button>
</form>

      </div>

</div> <!-- /container full -->
```

The above is my code for my form, I am using the full width bootstrap layout within Angular.js. Here is a screen of the output.

[image]

The two input boxes are within a parent div that is 100% wide, I am trying to center the two input boxes so that it does not lose it's responsiveness when resized.

I have tried

- .text-center
- margin: auto

without any success.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create plunker ?

Comment: Try use `col-xs-offset-[number]`; Also You can try `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Are you using a 12 grid? If so than add the `col-xs-offset-2` class to the first  `form-group`

Comment: @bumpyI am using jubotron http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: col-xs-offset-2 seemed to have work

Comment: @bumpy just found a problem with  
col-xs-offset-2, when the form has resized to mobile size the input box width are too small. If I set min width it overflows.

Comment: @user3754111 Try using `sm` instead of `xs`: `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-offset-2`

Comment: @bumpy perfect! Where can I read about the different types sm, xs  etc

Comment: @user3754111 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options